# Bitwise OR to represent an array of booleans

Tags: java, android, bitwise-operators, binary-operators

First of all, I am very new and poor informed in bitwise operations staff, so sorry if my question will seem dumb..

So I have 5 checkboxes in my Android app, and the state of these checkboxes need to be synced with backend. But instead of an simple JSON object with 5 elements with true/false values I get an integer (e.g 13), and need to send an integer to represent the state of all checkboxes. The API documentation says the following:

> FromUri Int32 visibility : visibility = "OR" operation of bit for
>   following values None = 0, NameVisibile = 1 | WebVisible = 2 |
>   MobileVisible = 4 | DOBVisible = 8 | AddressVisible = 16

So I guess this means that if I have for example checked `WebVisible`, `MobileVisible` and `DOBVisible` checkboxes I should do `2 + 4 + 8 = 14` and send number 14 to represent the state of my checkboxes?

and with the same logic if I get some integer from BE should I interpret it this way?

```
public void test(int value){
    if (value >= 16){
        addressVisible = true;
        value -= 16;
    } else {
        addressVisible = false;
    }

    if(value >= 8){
        dobVisible = true;
        value -= 8;
    } else {
        dobVisible = false;
    }

    if(value >= 4){
        mobileVisible = true;
        value -= 4;
    } else {
        mobileVisible = false;
    }

    if(value >= 2){
        webVisible = true;
        value -= 2;
    } else {
        webVisible = false;
    }

    if(value >= 1){
        nameVisibile = true;
    } else {
        nameVisibile = false;
    }
}
```

Is this a right way to solve this problem? May be there are more "smart" ways to do the same things using bitwise operators?

Comment: an AND is more common in masks: `if (value & 0x10) {}`. This way, you don't need to modify the value, and each test is independent.

Comment: What @njzk2 wrote is true. The statement he reported, however, is not valid Java code (`int` cannot be evaluated as `boolean`). The right statement, hence, is `if ((value & 0x10) != 0) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

The way this works is fairly simple.

```
Flag            Value   Binary

None            0       0x00000
NameVisibile    1       0x00001
WebVisible      2       0x00010
...
```

The bitwise OR works as such

```
0 | 0 = 0
1 | 0 = 1
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

So when you OR (|) together multiple flags you retain the state of each because each one only takes one place in the binary value.
For example

```
NameVisible | WebVisible = 0x00011
```

Now, to address your question. To extract the value, you can use the AND operator. AND works as such

```
0 & 0 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

So take the value from our example 0x00011 and AND (&) it with the flag you are testing for, say WebVisible

```
Value        WebVisible 
0x00011  &   0x00010     = 0x00010
```

Since that value is not zero, you know that WebVisible is true.

Here is concrete code you can adapt to your needs.

```
public void test(int value){
    int addressVisibleFlag = 16;
    ...

    addressVisible = (value & addressVisibleFlag) != 0;
    ....
}
```

Hopefully this helps. This is basically just an overview of the logic involved. This is untested and I have near-zero experience with Android but you should be able to do something with this.